# How do a write an Apache Rewrite rule to redirect requests to a directory to SSL?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I am trying to redirect all requests within a directory on a server to https. I have tried the following in a separate config (within the config.d directory), and in an .htaccess file. Neither work, but cause no errors.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

When I tried in a config file the above was within a  block.

**EDIT**
Here is my code in the config file:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/ssl_dir/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip xx.xx.xx.0/24
        Require ip ::1
    </RequireAny>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    </IfModule>  
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307025/force-https-on-certain-urls-and-force-http-for-all-others

My first answer mistakenly used SERVER_NAME, which does not necessarily equal HTTP_HOST.  The server name can be anything and very different from the domain name used to access it.

Comment: I tried your change, and get the same results. I added the bit of my code from the config. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried your changes, and the code from your quoted source..still to no avail. I must be missing something else.

Comment: is mod_rewrite loaded?  If not, your rewrite is not executed at all.

Comment: My server is Fedora, and I do have AllowOverride All - that should enable it, right?

Comment: No look for a line like this:  LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Comment: The line is in 00-base.conf

Comment: Got it! I had to use "HTTP_HOST" instead of "SERVER_NAME" in the rewrite rule. If you know why, can you add info to your answer so it helps the future? I'll mark your answer as the answer.